# "Lorentz gauge" or "Lorenz gauge"?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, terminology, gauge, linearized-theory

In electrodynamics there is a [gauge condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_gauge_condition) named after Ludvig Lorenz: $$\partial^\mu A_\mu = 0.$$
In general relativity we also have a gauge condition defined as follow:
$$\partial_\mu \gamma^{\mu\nu} = 0.$$
According to Wald's book (eq. 4.4.11, p. 75), this is called "Lorentz gauge." I was wondering if that's a mistake. According to some lecture notes, this is also called "Hilbert gauge."

Comment: It's definitely Lorenz, but understandably many authors confuse them. I was _this_ close in my thesis to making a "to T or not to T" pun about those names.

Comment: @J.G. That seems like an answer, not a comment (even though it is brief). Do you have a mnemonic (nemonic? pneumonic?) which might help those of us who struggle with silent or nearly-silent letters?

Comment: Can anyone provide the appropriate definitive references from the literature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Lorentz gauge" is a very popular error.

[arXiv:0803.0047 [physics.hist-ph]](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.0047) :

> The Lorenz condition/relation and gauge are named in honour of the
> Danish theoretical physicist Ludwig Valentin Lorenz (1829–1891), who
> has first published it in 1867 [5, 6] (see also [7, pp. 268-269, 291]
> and [8, 9]). However this condition was first introduced in lectures
> by Bernhard G. W. Riemann in 1861 as pointed in [7, p. 291]. It should
> be noted that the Lorenz condition/gauge is quite often erroneously
> referred as the Lorentz condition/gauge after the name of the Dutch
> theoretical physicist Hendrik Antoon Lorentz (1853–1928) as, e.g., in
> [10, p. 18], [11, p. 45] and [12, pp. 421-422, 426, 542]. The table
> below represents some results of searching over the Internet for
> “Lorenz gauge” and “Lorentz gauge.” We see that the situation is quite
> sad in favour of the wrong term, but there is a slight improvement
> during the last 3 years. [5] Ludwig Valentin Lorenz. Uber die
> Intensit¨at der Schwingungen des Lichts mit den ¨elektrischen
> Str¨omen. Annalen der Physik und Chemie, 131:243–263, 1867. [6] Ludwig
> Valentin Lorenz. On the identity of the vibrations of light with
> electrical currents. Philosophical Magazine, 34:287–301, 1867. [7]
> Edmund Whittaker. A history of the theories of aether and electricity,
> volume 1. The classical theories. of Harper torchbooks / The science
> library. Harper & brothers, New York, 1960. Originally published by
> Thomas Nelson & Son Ltd, London, 1910; revised and enlarged 1951. See
> also the 1989 edition: New York: Dover, 1989.